# Semitransparent PagerTabStrip with actionbar overlay

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm using a actionbar with `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` and some transparency. Additionally I'm using a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip`. The problem is the `PagerTabStrip` is now displayed underneath the actionbar.

Applying a margin to the `PagerTabStrip` doesn't work at all and applying a margin to the whole `ViewPager` prevents the content (A `ScrollView` inside a `Fragment`) to scroll underneath the actionbar and the PagerTabStrip, which should be semitransparent too.

So currently I'm stucked with [image: this]

which isn't ideal at all :D

Anyone got an idea to implement this behaviour?

Edit: so the problem consists of 2 parts. Making the content scroll underneath the `PagerTabStrip` and moving the `PagerTitleStrip`.

Comment: Navigation Tabs aren't ideal because I don't want to miss the small size of the strip and it looks awkward if you open the navigation drawer (The tabs are overlaying the drawer too).

Answer (score 2):

Add a view above the pager tab strip with a height of
 ?android:attr/actionBarSize
It will take the height of the action bar and "push" the content down.

Comment: Tried it. Not working. The View isn't rendered or "overwritten" by the Layout the ViewPager set.

Comment: For the record, this worked for me.  <!--this fake view is to cover up for actionbar overlay-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/fake_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>